# what's ::after do here: <div class=foo><span>bar</span>::after</div>

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble understanding what the :after css tag does when inserted into HTML code. For example,

```
<div class=foo>
  <span>xyz</span>
  ::after
</div>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: In this example, it does nothing (other than adding a text node inside the div with the content `"::after"`). For a basic tutorial: [CSS Pseudo Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)

Answer (score 4):

> **::after** is a pseudo element which allows you to insert content onto a page from CSS (without it needing to be in the HTML). While the
>   end result is not actually in the DOM, it appears on the page as if it
>   is, and would essentially be like this:

```
div::after {
  content: "hi";
}
```

> ::before is exactly the same only it inserts the content before any
>   other content in the HTML instead of after. The only reasons to use
>   one over the other are:

- You want the generated content to come before the element content,
  positionally.
- The ::after content is also "after" in source-order, so it will
  position on top of ::before if stacked on top of each other
  naturally.

  CSS2 syntax = 
  element:after  { style properties }

  CSS3 syntax =
  element::after { style properties }

```css
.exciting-text::after {
  content: "<- now this *is* exciting!"; 
  color: green;
}

.boring-text::after {
   content:    "<- BORING!";
   color:      red;
}
```

```html
<p class="boring-text">Here is some good old boring text.</p>
<p>Here is some moderate text that is neither boring nor exciting.</p>
<p class="exciting-text">Contributing to MDN is easy and fun.
Just hit the edit button to add new live samples, or improve existing samples.</p>
```

Comment: I think I get the definition of the selector, it's just its usage within the .html document that's got me confused. Like, the example I gave in my question -

Comment: ::after is the position or space or area, here whatever we applied ::after using jquery or javascript or css that will be placed

Comment: In my code you can see <- BORING! is appeared using ::after technique. and you can see it by using inspect element

Answer (score 0):

It's not a tag, it's a pseudo-element selector used in CSS that creates an element `:before` or `:after` the targeted element.

> ## What Does A Pseudo-Element Do?
>
> A pseudo-element does exactly what the word implies. It creates a
> phoney element and inserts it before or after the content of the
> element that you’ve targeted.
>
> The word “pseudo” is a transliteration of a Greek word that basically
> means “lying, deceitful, false.” So, calling them pseudo-elements is
> appropriate, because they don’t actually change anything in the
> document. Rather, they insert ghost-like elements that are visible to
> the user and that are style-able in the CSS.
>
> http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the easiest example to learn.

```
div {
  background: black;
}

div:before {
  content: "i appear before the div ";
}

div:after {
  content: " i appear after the div";
}

<div>hello</div>
```

Output: "i appear before the div hello i appear after the div"

It's usually good to use when you insert icons or images before or after an element like buttons with icons, etc.